# Recurrent neural network (LSTM) dimensions error

Tags: lstm, rnn

I have data in a dataframe named `ddf` as follows:

```
labels          X
L1          [1,2,3,7,8,9...]
L1          [4,2,6,9,8,7...]
...
L2          [5,6,8,9,6,3...]
L2          [7,8,5,6,9,0...]
...
```

There are 250 rows, 7 labels and 2000 elements in every list under X. These 2000 elements are values of a signal over a period of about 60 seconds.

I am trying to build a recurrent neural network for above data. Following is my code:

```
Xall = ddf['X'].values
Xall = np.array(Xall)

ydf = pd.get_dummies(ddf.drop('X', axis=1))
Yall = np.array(ydf.values)

# Split the data
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(Xall, Yall,  test_size=0.1, random_state=0) 

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Embedding, LSTM, Dense
model_lstm = Sequential()
model_lstm.add(Embedding(2000, 128))
model_lstm.add(LSTM(100, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model_lstm.add(LSTM(200, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model_lstm.add(Dense(Yall.shape[1], activation='softmax'))
model_lstm.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model_lstm.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=50, verbose=True, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))
```

However, I am getting error at second LSTM layer:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_2: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2
```

I think this has something to do with LSTM arguments. Also are arguments of Embedding layer OK? How are both these adjusted? Where is the error coming from and how can it be solved? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT after comments***

> Also are arguments of Embedding layer OK?

Yes. But You need to pass `return_sequences = True` in the first LSTM layer so that it will pass sequences to the next LSTM layer.

*From the docs*

`return_sequences: Boolean. Whether to return the last output in the output sequence, or the full sequence.`

> How are both these adjusted?

From the [docs](https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/).

input_dim: 
Size of the vocabulary, i.e. maximum integer index + 1. This determines the largest integer in the input data. The largest integer in the input should be no larger than the vocabulary size. This should be the

output_dim:  Dimension of the dense embedding. int >= 0

input_length: Length of input sequences, when it is constant. This argument is required if you are going to connect Flatten then Dense layers upstream (without it, the shape of the dense outputs cannot be computed).

I am posting code below for dummy data. The size of vocabulary has been taken 100.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Embedding, LSTM, Dense
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
input_array = np.random.randint(100, size=(250, 2000))
input_y = np.random.randint(7, size = (250))

Y_dumy = pd.get_dummies(input_y)
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(input_array, Y_dumy,  
test_size=0.1, random_state=0)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim = 100, output_dim = 64, input_length=2000))
model.add(LSTM(100, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2, return_sequences 
=True))
model.output_shape

#Output shape should be:
#model.output_shape = (None, 2000, 64)
#3D tensor with shape: (batch_size, sequence_length, output_dim)

model.add(LSTM(200, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(Y_dumy.shape[1], activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics= 
['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=50, verbose=True, validation_data= 
(X_test, Y_test))`
```

> Where is the error coming from and how can it be solved?

I believe the error is coming because of absence of input_length. For similar errors please have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42335856/keras-valueerror-input-0-is-incompatible-layer-issues?noredirect=1&lq=1).

*After the comments*
The error is coming because of `return_sequences =False` in the first LSTM layer.

Comment: Actually, my data is a regularly sampled electrical signal values and not text. It will be great if you can edit your answer in view of this.

Comment: Also, the error is coming from second LSTM statement and not first. Code works all right if second LSTM layer is removed.

Comment: You mean this layer: model_lstm.add(LSTM(100, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))

Comment: No, second LSTM layer: the  one with `200`.

Comment: Maybe you need return_sequences set to True in the first layer i.e. model_lstm.add(LSTM(100, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2, return_sequences = True))

Comment: With `return_sequences = True`, the model gets built and is compiled but throws an error on `fit` statement: `ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (231, 7)`

Comment: Now it does not work even after removing second LSTM layer (one which has 200 in it).

Comment: I have edited the code in my answer. The code compiles and also does not throw error on model.fit(). Please check whether the dimensions that you have given in your code are consistent. You can copy the code in your python interpreter to run it.

Comment: The model.output_shape is (None, 2000, 100) and not (None, 2000, 64) as you have written. However, the code is working. Why did you choose input and output dimensions to be 100 and 64, respectively? What is the range possible for this?

Comment: I put input dim = 100, because random ints that I generated for input_array were in the range of [0, 100). So, vocabulary is 100. And I just chose 64 as the output_dim. :)